# eliminar fila indexada de dataframe obtenido de la web

Tags: python, dataframe, index

Tengo el siguiente dataframe obtenido de una pagina web
trabajado en python.

Deseo poder eliminar la fila indexada que me aparece ya que no puedo continuar
analizando.

Agradezco de antemano su apoyo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que has intentado? cual es el error?

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema es esa primera fila puedes hacer que se convierta en el header del dataframe con

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Si lo que quieres es simplemente eliminarla no veo más problema que seleccionar el df con ese offset:

```
df = df[1:]
```